# Is there any way to override log4j.properties programmatically in webapplication

Tags: java, spring, logging, log4j, slf4j

Is it possible to override log4j.properties in code level based on some properties in data base. I have a situation where I want to have logging to use log4j.properties by default and changed to values available in data base.

Comment: is it about getting a specific level of logs printed at runtime? not very clear from the question

Comment: yes but the level will be decided based on values available in data base table.

Comment: You can store Log level value in DB and have a scheduled worker checking app configuration every minute or so.

Comment: yes is it about getting a specific level of logs printed at runtime